# Structure prototype?

Tags: c++, struct, header, structure

How do I put a struct in a separate file? I can do it with functions by putting the function prototype in a header file e.g. file.h and the function body in a file like file.cpp and then using the include directive #include "file.h" in the source file with main. Can anybody give a simple example of doing the same thing with a structure like the one below? I'm using dev-c++.

```
struct person{
  string name;
  double age;
  bool sex;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

Just declare

```
struct person;
```

It is called [class forward declaration](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml). In C++, structs are classes with all members public by default.

Answer (score 4):

**If you're talking about a struct declaration:**

*person.h* :

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_
#define PERSON_H_
struct person{ 
  string name; 
  double age; 
  bool sex; 
};
#endif
```

Then you just include person.h in the .cpp files where you need that struct.

**If you're talking about a (global) variable of the struct:**

*person.h* :

```
#ifndef PERSON_H_
#define PERSON_H_
struct person{ 
  string name; 
  double age; 
  bool sex; 
};
extern struct Person some_person;
#endif
```

And in **one** of your .cpp files you need this line, at global scope,that holds the definition for 'some_person'

```
struct Person some_person;
```

Now every .cpp file that needs to access the global 'some_person' variable can include the person.h file.

Comment: Your first bit of code is a struct definition, not just a struct declaration.